# Django Rest Framework, How to update nested values in serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

In DRF, I would like to post bulk transactions to my rest endpoint.

On the following `Serializer` what would be the correct way to create a nested field of values for `transactions` in DFR?

Do you call `create` **for each transaction** on `TransactionItemSerializer`

OR

Call `save()` on the Transaction model inside `MasterSerializer` create myself>

For example:

```
class MasterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    transactions = TransactionItemSerializer(many=True)  # A nested list of 'transaction' items.
```

1 . Update transactions on `MasterSerializer`.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    transactions = validated_data.pop('transactions')
    # for each transaction do Transaction Save()
```

2 . Somehow call the `create` method of the `TransactionItemSerializer` within `MasterSerializer` create method for each transaction i.e

```
  class MasterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    transactions = TransactionItemSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ['transactions']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        transactions = validated_data.pop('transactions')
        # call create on for each transaction TransactionItemSerializer.create() here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model name is 'Transaction' and it has '`master`' field referencing a master transaction, you can do:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    transactions = validated_data.pop('transactions', [])
    instance = super().create(validated_data)

    for transaction in transactions:
        Transaction.objects.create(master=instance, **transaction)

    instance.refresh_from_db()
    return instance
```

Comment: Just so I understand. Transaction.objects.create what will that call? the model create or the create method on the transition ModelSerializer?

Comment: It will call model's `create` method, you don't need the latter, since the data is already validated through the serializer and you can simply use the validated_data to create a new object using model's `create`

Comment: My master `Serialize` has this field... `transactions = TransactionSerializer(many=True)  By calling the model to create as suggested above, would this not bypass the `TransactionSerializer` create ? Hope it's not silly question, I'm trying to understand this better. ps TransactionSerializer is a `ModelSerializer`

Comment: maybe insetad of above, would it be better to do this?... `        transaction_serializer = TransactionSerializer(
            data=transactions, many=True
        )`

Comment: yes, you can do so, if you have no problem referencing the master transaction in the `TransactionSerializer`, then why not?

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful. So, my takeaway is I have two options. I can call the transaction's model passing in the list and create each transaction. The second option is to do the same but via a `ModelSerializer` which gives me the benefit of representation of the nested transaction object.